# Flex 3 Zendamf Remote Debugging

Tags: flex3, remoting, zend-amf

I'm having some problems debugging my zendamf remote. I'm on a Mac running MAMP. I've got Flex 3 with the SDK 3.6 and Flash Player 10.

I've got Charles running. I don't see anything too weird although, I'm not sure what I should be looking for. I get 200 OK for everything except:

> http://localhost/zendamf_remote_flex_dcre
>   301 POST localhost
>   /zendamf_remote_flex_dcre7 ms
>   1.16 KB Complete null

Later down Charles' list, I see:

> http://localhost/zendamf_remote_flex_dcre/
>   200 GET localhost
>   /zendamf_remote_flex_dcre/ 186 ms 533
>   bytes Complete
>
> Zend Amf
>   Endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I forgot "-service" in the compiler option settings.